# PHP 5.3.13 Unexpected token < with json_encode

Tags: php, json

I setup a local site but when I goto it I get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` which brings me to this line of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
pepsiMedia.loadConfig(<?= json_encode($this->config) ?>);
$(document).ready(pepsiMedia.ready);
</script>
```

I am assuming it has something to do with the json_encode or my PHP version, what can I do to fix this?

I am bit hesitant about showing what $this->config is as it has sensitive  information, let me know if you need it and I will try to recreate it without sensitive information.

Comment: Are you sure it's parsing the PHP in the first place? Can you check in the source code?=

Comment: What is the extension of the file ?

Comment: Did you enable `short_open_tag`? Before 5.4.0, the `<?= ... ?>` shorthand requires it, although it should be enabled by default.

Comment: Sounds more like a JS error than a PHP error. Are you sure that `<?=` is working on your system and the PHP code is actually being executed?

Comment: try <?php echo json_encode($this->config); ?> instead. if that doesn't work try printing $this->config maybe it's not accessible.

Comment: Is your php short tag `<?=` `On` in `php.ini`?

Comment: $this->config is accessible `<?php print_r($this->config); die; ?>` I put that before the code in my question. Its displaying correctly.

Comment: Thanks netcoder...put it in a question and I will check it

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
pepsiMedia.loadConfig(<?php echo json_encode($this->config); ?>);
$(document).ready(pepsiMedia.ready);
</script>
```